# ListView setOnItemClickListener not working when ListView row contain RadioButton

Tags: android, listview

Please do not say that this is duplicate question, because i search on google and try every answer then also not getting result. In my Listview row contain one TextView and three Radio button.
**Problem is**
When i click on other side in particular row then Listview `setOnItemClickListener` work fine but problem is when i click on radio button then `setOnItemClickListener` not called i don't know why ?

I want that when i click or select any redioButton then call one method, I know that this is possible by adapter but i want radio button click event in listview `onItemClick()`  method.
Sorry for bad english, Thanks in advance and help would be appreciate

**xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:background="@drawable/student_row_background">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_attendance_studentName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="@color/headerActionbar"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rg_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center|right"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="21dp"
                android:text="P"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton_present"
                android:textColor="@color/headerActionbar"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:buttonTint="@color/headerActionbar"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="21dp"
                android:background="@color/dialogTextColor"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="21dp"
                android:text="A"
                android:textColor="@color/headerActionbar"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton_absent"
                android:buttonTint="@color/headerActionbar"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="21dp"
                android:background="@color/dialogTextColor"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="21dp"
                android:text="L"
                android:textColor="@color/headerActionbar"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton_leave"
                android:buttonTint="@color/headerActionbar"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is **java file**

```
        lv_studentList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

                     RadioButton radioButton_present = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton_present);
                     RadioButton radioButton_absent = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton_absent);
                     RadioButton radioButton_leave = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton_leave);

                    if (!radioButton_present.isChecked() && !radioButton_absent.isChecked()
                    && !radioButton_leave.isChecked())
                    {
                        constant.showSnackBar("Please select at least one attendance option");
                    }
                    else if(radioButton_present.isChecked())
                    {
                        constant.showSnackBar("Student is present");
                    }
                    else if (radioButton_absent.isChecked())
                    {
                        constant.showSnackBar("Student is absent");
                    }
                   else if (radioButton_leave.isChecked())
                   {
                        constant.showSnackBar("Student is leave");
                   }
             }
        });
```

Comment: What is `lv_studentList`?

Comment: it's listview object

Comment: I don't see a `ListView` in your xml. Further on why are you not setting a `OnCheckedListener` on the `RadioGroup`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `View` parameter of `onItemClick()` method to find the `RadioGroup` or `RadioButton` view. Then use that view as per requirement.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

            RadioGroup group = group = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.rg_1);
            final RadioButton radioButton_present = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton_present);
            final RadioButton radioButton_absent = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton_absent);
            final RadioButton radioButton_leave = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton_leave);
            group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                    if (!radioButton_present.isChecked() && !radioButton_absent.isChecked()
                            && !radioButton_leave.isChecked())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please select at least one attendance option",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else if(radioButton_present.isChecked())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Student is present",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else if (radioButton_absent.isChecked())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Student is absent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else if (radioButton_leave.isChecked())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Student is leave",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });


        }
```

Comment: @Ninja, I have updated the answer with working code that I have tried

Comment: 1+ It's works great. thank you so much, i am trying last two days. thanks again